# How can I isolate which parameter is throwing error in Insert Method?

Tags: asp.net, database, parameters, insert

I'm passing parameters (over 30 in all) from a system.data.dataset into a tableadapter insert method, but I'm getting an "Input string was not in a correct format" exception.

The error points to the method that is throwing, which is great, but is there a way I can tell exactly which parameter is throwing the error?

(Sorry about the code formatting -- I fought with it for 5 minutes before giving up)

```
myTableAdapter.Insert( 
    row["GUID"].ToString(),
    Convert.ToInt16(row["domain"].ToString()),
    Convert.ToInt16(row["plan"].ToString()),
    Convert.ToInt16(row["type"].ToString()),
    Convert.ToInt16(row["type_alt"].ToString()), ...etc
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bunch of `Int16` variables, convert into them, then pass to the `Insert()` method

```
Int16 domain = Convert.ToInt16(row["domain"].ToString());
Int16 plan = Convert.ToInt16(row["plan"].ToString());
```

..etc..

```
myTableAdapter.Insert( 
    row["GUID"].ToString(),
    domain,
    plan,
```

..etc..